# How to click one href that changes every login?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a click event on this href link

```
<li><a href="TerminalReport.aspx?pid=20635&amp;key=7G76887">Report</a></li>
```

The PID and KEY change everytime, so I cant use .navigate .. Is there any code to do like a partial match for looking for `"*" & "TerminalReport" & "*"`  and click?

[image]  [image]

The code is to long to post here, it is telling me to add more details so I will post the code from the begining to the part I'm getting stuck unles I use .navigate

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Dc_User As String
    Dim Dc_Pass As String
    Dim Dc_URL As String
    Dim txtNam As Object, txtPwd As Object

    Dc_User = "LOGIN"
    Dc_Pass = "PASSWORD"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.solarmanpv.com/portal/LoginPage.aspx"

        While IE.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend
        IE.document.getElementById("uNam").Value = Dc_User
        IE.document.getElementById("uPwd").Value = Dc_Pass

        IE.document.getElementById("Loginning").Click
        
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#

    'THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
    .navigate "https://www.solarmanpv.com/portal/Terminal/TerminalReport.aspx?pid=20635&key=78775J8"
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Like` to perform wildcard matching - get all the link elements under that id and check the href property of each

Comment: I'm a newbie at this, can you give me one exemple on how to do that?

Comment: Do you already have the page loaded?  Are you using IE automation or something like selenium?

Comment: I do have the page loaded, and yes I'm using IE automation, the rest of the code is working, if you need I can add all the code to the question.

Comment: That's usually a good way to get helpful suggestions - much easier to add a couple of lines than to write a whole method...

Comment: I have added the code, it is behind login so if you need it I could try to send you in private, not sure if stackoverflow have this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Dc_User As String
    Dim Dc_Pass As String
    Dim Dc_URL As String
    Dim txtNam As Object, txtPwd As Object
    Dim links As Object, link As Object

    Dc_User = "LOGIN"
    Dc_Pass = "PASSWORD"

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.solarmanpv.com/portal/LoginPage.aspx"
        WaitFor IE
        
        IE.document.getElementById("uNam").Value = Dc_User
        IE.document.getElementById("uPwd").Value = Dc_Pass
        IE.document.getElementById("Loginning").Click
        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5) '5 secs

        Set links = .document.getElementById("ct100_cur_item_list").getElementsByTagName("A")
        For Each link In links
            Debug.Print link.href
            If link.href Like "*TerminalReport*" Then
                link.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next link
    
    End With

End Sub

Sub WaitFor(IE As Object)
    While IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I needed, thanks for taking your time to help me!